# querying a datetime field only using the date part of the record

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with a field Datetime that include date and time like this as an example....

```
2015-07-15 12:00:00.000
```

I'm trying to query this data but only search by the date part....

```
2015-07-15 <-- like this
```

example query

```
Select * from tableA where Date = '07/15/2015'
```

Currently it does not yield any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it as a Date if you are on a newer version of SQL Server...

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE CAST([Date] as Date) = '07/15/2015'
```

However this may not allow indexes to be used...

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from tableA where Date >= '2015-07-15' and Date < '2015-07-16'
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from TableA where Convert(date,Date)='07/15/2015'

Answer (score 1):

Use convert function
 Convert(date,Date)